# on click event and pass value to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an on click event that calls a function but it does not work:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderDetails)
{
   <tr class="text-center" id="@item.DetailId">
       <td class="product-remove" onclick="DeleteOrderDetail(@item.DetailId)"><a><span class="ion-ios-close"></span></a></td>
   </tr>
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function DeleteOrderDetail(orderDetailId) {
            debugger;
            $.get("/Account/RemoveCart?orderDetailId=" + orderDetailId,
                function () {
                    $("#" + orderDetailId).hide('slow');
                });
    </script>
}
```

error:Uncaught ReferenceError: DeleteOrderDetail is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

A search on the internet revealed that I had to use a addEventListener
But in this case, I can not pass the `@item.DetailId` to the function

Comment: First of all you have to correct your code. You are not closing the fuction, } is missing.

Comment: Im surprised it let you run when you're missing a bracket

Comment: Also wrap the id you pass in quotes `DeleteOrderDetail('@item.DetailId')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already mentioned your syntax issue in comments to the question

However if you do

```
$(".product-remove").on("click", function() { 
  const $parent = $(this).closest("tr"), detailId = $parent.attr("id");
  $.get(`/Account/RemoveCart?orderDetailId=${detailId}`,function()) {
    $parent.hide('slow'); 
  });
});
```

Then NO need for inline handlers or passing IDs

the code above replaces ALL your posted code

If you add the details dynamically, you need to delegate to nearest static container

```
$("#tableId").on("click",".product-remove", function() { 
  const $parent = $(this).closest("tr"), detailId = $parent.attr("id");
  $.get(`/Account/RemoveCart?orderDetailId=${detailId}`,function()) {
    $parent.hide('slow'); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some `syntax` errors.

You did not close the `}` of your function.

```
        function DeleteOrderDetail(orderDetailId) {
        debugger;
        $.get("/Account/RemoveCart?orderDetailId=" + orderDetailId,
            function () {
                $("#" + orderDetailId).hide('slow');
            });
         }
```

And in this part of your code, you should pass data in `''`.

```
 <td class="product-remove" onclick="DeleteOrderDetail('@item.DetailId')"><a><span class="ion-ios-close"></span></a></td>
```

Comment: This can all be avoided by NOT having inline handlers - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769765/295783)

Comment: Thankyou
 <td class="product-remove" onclick="DeleteOrderDetail('@item.DetailId')">
The problem was with this character **'**
The absence } was a mistake in the copy

Comment: @sina As I mention in my answer, the problem is more than that. It is much better to remove inline event handlers and access parent elements using closest

Comment: @mplungjan
Thank you, your solution worked well, but which one is better? And why?

Comment: @sina It is not recommended to have inline handler due to the separation of markup and functionality. But also clarity and DRYness (don’t repeat yourself). Lastly my code is much easier to maintain - for example if the name of the server variables change, my code does not need any modification except the url which also should be outside the script

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation